# Organize the models in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just read the official Symfony 3 docs and point when I need to retrieve objects from database I should use something like this:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
```

Here Product is just an entity class with no parent, so Doctrine work with it through annotations. But I'm not sure it's a good idea to hardcode the model name in quotes. What if later I conclude to name the model *Good*, should I search through the whole project and replace Product on Good. I Laravel for example, each model extends the base model class so I could write : `Product::model()->find('nevermind')` . Is there any such option in Symfony 3.3?

Comment: I didn't get the changing Product to Good in this example. In each case you have to refactor every single piece. `Product::model() -> Good::model()`, `'AppBundle:Product' -> 'AppBundle:Good'`, `Product::class -> Good::class` isn't it? I think the closest is the answer of @COil Btw. doctrine has different approach here. Model shouldn't know anything about database or repository. It should have as few dependencies as possible. Good ides/plugins can also resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not shure if it is a solution for your problem, but you can write:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository(Product::class);
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried it yet but looks pretty good. At least I see no quotes =)

Answer (score 1):

The `$em->getRepository('...')` returns a mixed datatype (depends on the first parameter). Even you write `$repository = $em->getRepository(Product::class);` the IDE cannot resolve the real datatype. I suggest this method (pseudo code):

```
/**
 * Get product repo
 *
 * @return ProductRepository
 */
 public function getProductRepository() 
 {
     return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Product::class);
 }

 /**
  * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
  */
 public function getEntityManager(): EntityManager
 {
     return $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the repository as a service like this:

```
services:
    app.product_repo:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
        arguments:
            - AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

Then in your controller:

```
$repository = $em->get('app.product_repo');
```

Well at least it works with PHPStorm and its Symfony plugin. Having auto-complete for services is really a must.